# newman running on gitlab timed out with 503

Tags: gitlab, postman, gitlab-ci, newman

I have made a newman collection for some calls. One of those call is to call a flask server, I also have a .gitlab-ci file to configure all the tests, all of them run perfectly until today. It wasn't able to call the flask server from gitlab, instead it takes around 1 min and timed out with status code 503. Locally seems working fine. I also try to make curl calls directly to the ip address and it returns the response. Any ideas on why this could happen? What could be changed either from newman side or gitlab side? Don't know if this is related to the proxy issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would search on the receptor side. Because you are geting a valid response code (503) as a response. So the connection to your flask server seems to exist in principle. If you are using your flask server as a gateway, you must check the connection between flask an the other service.